# Редактирование стиля ползунка jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Привет всем,

Как я могу скрыть линию в jquery-ui за ползунком?

И сделать отображение ползунка только при наведении?

Comment: так что-ли ?

    .ui-slider {
        border: none;
    }

Comment: Мне кажется или это уберет только обводку? а не саму линию